# Android MediaPlayer W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (703, 203)

Tags: android, android-studio, warnings, shoutcast, internet-radio

I want to make radio player example but i have some errors. I can't fix it.

My Source Code

```
String url = ""; //Shoutcast Radio URL
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        mp.setDataSource(url);
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e(TAG, "SecurityException");
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e(TAG, "IllegalStateException");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException");
    }
```

My Error (Logcat)

```
E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (703, 203)
W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (701, 0)
W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (702, 0)
W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (702, 0)
```

Comment: Information. `701` means MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START and `702` means MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END

Comment: Yes I know but how i fix it?

Comment: I am also face the same issues , When i try with Nexus 5(Updated to lolipop ) every time it stuck for seconds and start play again and again struck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *"Should have subtitle controller already set"* text is just a warning not an error. It references to the new implementation of MediaPlayer in [Android Kitkat 4.4](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#Multimedia) (they added subtitles capabilities for videos, but for some reason it tries to use subtitles even if the media is just audio).

So you can just ignore that warning.

If it doesn't play you can try to use the *OnPreparedListener* just after *mp.prepare();* with *mp.start();*:

```
mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mp.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: That seems to be something about the stream, can you play it correctly with some player on the device?

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue, apparently we can't solve it according to:

http://www.piterwilson.com/blog/2014/03/11/android-mediaplayer-not-quite-there-yet/